# Phase Measurement 3d visualize when unwrapped phase function

Tags: matplotlib, 3d-reconstruction

Recently I have tried the phase-shifting-profilometry method to get a 3D surface.
[Input Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8BMt.gif)
[Object's Phase Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QueKS.png)

Everything went smoothly until I found out that it becomes a Diagonal plane/ Diagonal surface when visualizing the surface due to the unwrapped phase algorithm.

[3D object Visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jysU.png)

I want to ask whether there is any method to make the surface horizontal (like the XY plane).

Sorry that I can not post images here because "I need at least 10 reputation to post images", so Images will be on the link below.

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8BMt.gif

2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QueKS.png

3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jysU.png

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ju Lee,

what you are actually plotting is the phase map which can be used to calculate the 3D object. The easiest way (which is only an approximation) to get a depth map is to calculate the phase difference to the phase map of a reference plane (without an object on it):

```
depth(x,y) ~ a*(phase_map(x,y) - phase_map_reference(x,y)),
```

where a is a scaling factor you have to determine experimentally. This "easy" procedure is roughly adapted from Takeda's famous 1983 paper: https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.22.003977.
See formula 22 therein for small phase differences.

A more accurate procedure giving the full 3D pointcloud directly from the phase can be found in Zhang's 2006 paper https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.14.009120.
But therefore, you have to calibrate the camera-projector system and calculate an "absolute" phase_map. This typically needs a lot of work, but references therefore are linked in Zhang's paper.

Have fun!